# Issues at having definitions, examples, etc. numbered in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, numbering, environments, examples

everyone! I am trying to have definitions, theorems, examples and exercises properly numbered. I've even tried to have the "examples" that span more than one slide numbered by using \addtocounter with  no avail. Somehow I can't manage to be error free and have what I desire. Please, help!

This is the coding:

```
\documentclass[Spanish,notheorems, handout]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, mathtools}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz} % zeichnen
\usetikzlibrary{cd} % kommutierende Diagramme
%\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\selectlanguage{spanish}
\uselanguage{spanish}
\languagepath{spanish}
\decimalpoint
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
%\usepackage[lastexercise]{exercise}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide,tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


%%%%%%%%%%%%% WATERMARK  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage{background}
%\backgroundsetup{
%placement=center,
%scale=4,
%contents={Educativo},
%opacity=0.7
%}
%\setbeamertemplate{background}{\BgMaterial}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcounter{theo}[section]
\setcounter{theo}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetheo}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{theo}}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definizione}[theo]{Definizione}
\newtheorem{esempio}[theo]{Esempio}
\newtheorem{algoritmo}[theo]{Algoritmo}
\newtheorem{osservazione}[theo]{Osservazione}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{corollario}[theo]{Corollario}
\newtheorem{proposizione}[theo]{Proposizione}


\newenvironment{theo}[2][]{%
   \refstepcounter{theo}%
   \ifstrempty{#1}%
      {\mdfsetup{%
         frametitle={%
            \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
            \node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=black!20]
            {\strut Teorema~\thetheo};}%
         }%
      }%
      {\mdfsetup{%
         frametitle={%            
            \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
            \node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=black!20]
            {\strut Teorema~\thetheo~(#1).};}%
         }%
      }%
   \mdfsetup{innertopmargin=10pt,linecolor=black!30,%
             linewidth=2pt,topline=true,%
             frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax}
   \begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=gray!10]\relax\label{#2}}{\end{mdframed}%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym, amsfonts, pgf}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicefrac,xfrac}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{adforn}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setbeamertemplate{theorem}[ams style]
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\newenvironment{example*}
  {\addtocounter{theorem}{-1}\example}
  {\endexample}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\secname\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}


\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}



\newtcolorbox{mybox}{
  enhanced,
  left=0pt,
  right=0pt,
  top=8pt,
  bottom=8pt,
  colback=white,
  colframe=red,
  width=\textwidth,
  enlarge left by=0mm,
  boxsep=5pt,
  fontupper=\itshape\small,
  arc=4pt,
  outer arc=4pt,
  leftupper=1.5cm,
  overlay={
    \node[anchor=west] 
      at ([xshift=10pt] $ (frame.north west)!0.5!(frame.south west) $ )
       {\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{2.pdf}};}
       }




%Information to be included in the title page:
\title{Matemática Financiera II}
\author{Profesor Abreu}
\institute{Universidad Cat\'olica Santo Domingo}
\date{2021}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}
```

Comment: Pleas complete the code with several examples of theorems, definitions, etc. and finish it with `\end{document}`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.